# php onclick once inside input

Tags: javascript, php

```
  <progress value="0" max="100" id="p1"></progress> 

<div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Dq[1]" value="<?=$i?>" onClick='incr();'> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function incr() { 
var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 + 1;
}
</script>
```

my intention is make the question between 1-10 point can only be clicked once , but the input was generate by php so if i put the onclick inside input , each radio i clicked will be increasing the progress bar , i only need the radio only be clicked once and the progress bar remain the same % it have , lets each question is 1% once clicked it only increasing 1% , when reclick it still 1%.

or and i also dont wanted use jquery.

Comment: Are you saying once an answer is selected the user is unable to change their answer?

Comment: sorry let me repost again

Comment: i was trying to make a progress bar when user can only clicked between the 1-10 point , so each question can be clicked once but can br reclick again.

Comment: Still not 100% sure I understand, I've posted an answer below for you, let me know if I've got anything wrong by commenting on that and I'll see if I can help you out :)

Comment: please read again i update my post , thank you ~~

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what it is you're asking here (judging by the down votes it would appear others are too).

Some general tips for asking questions on StackOverflow:

- Your question should be clear (it's difficult to actually judge what you're asking here)
- Your code should ideally be presented in a readable manner (the PHP/HTML code you've provided is all on one line, and considering the question is regarding JavaScript functionality, and we don't have access to the rest of your PHP code, the PHP code is useless in terms of the question, and makes answering your question more effort)
- [JSFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/) are usually helpful when asking a frontend question like this (it means less wasted time replicating the issue)

Try and follow the above suggestions when asking a question, the list is by no means all inclusive though, you should also really read through the [guidelines on asking questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Now onto your actual question.

I'm guessing you want your code to function as follows:

- A user can only select an option once
- Once an option has been selected it should be added to the numerical contents of a paragraph

Assuming I've got the above correct (let me know if not) the following code should work for you:

HTML:

```
<p id="answerResult">1</p>

<div class="allQuestion" id="allQuestion">
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="1" /> 1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="2" /> 2<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="3" /> 3<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="4" /> 4<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="5" /> 5<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="6" /> 6<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="7" /> 7<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="8" /> 8<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="9" /> 9<br />
    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" value="10" /> 10<br />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// the paragraph that contains information about your currently selected answer
var answerSummary = document.getElementById('answerResult');
// the container of the radio buttons
var answersContainer = document.getElementById("allQuestion");
// the radio buttons
var answerOptions = answersContainer.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < answerOptions.length; i++) {
    answerOptions[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        // change the paragraph to show the currently selected value
        answerSummary.innerHTML = answerSummary.innerHTML + " " + this.value;

        // disable all radio buttons once an options has been selected
        for(var i = 0; i < answerOptions.length; i++) {
            answerOptions[i].disabled = true;
        }
    });
}
```

And a link to this code in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/44mvrftu/4/

I've quite significantly refactored your code to try and make it more readable, maintainable and easy to understand, somethings I've changed:

- Better variable names (v1 should never be a variable name)
- No 'onclick' in the HTML, you should never really do this as it means you're mingling HTML and JavaScript (presentation and functionality) which makes maintainability more difficult, and is arguably less performant in some ways. Let me know if you find the way I've added the onclick event handler confusing and I'll try and help you understand, alternatively you could modify the above code to use 'onclick' in the HTML.
- I removed the PHP (this was necessary for me to create a working demo)
- I've used pure JavaScript, this would be easier and cleaner to implement in jQuery, and would also ensure it worked in older browsers (the above code will only reliably work in modern browsers) but you've not said anything about jQuery so I've assumed you've not used it.

I hope I've got that right? Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: my intention is make the question between 1-10 point can only be clicked once , but the input was generate by php so if i put the onclick inside input , each radio i clicked will be increasing the progress bar , i only need the radio only be clicked once and the progress bar remain the same % it have , lets each question is 1% once clicked it only increasing 1% , when reclick it still 1%.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, I've not got time to write a full response now but I'll get back to you later

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear, if you are saying you want onclick only once use [jQuery .one(),see details here](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what you want? You can use both PHP and Javascript but it depends on what you want to do.

The jQuery solution:

```
$("input").one("click", function () {
alert($("input[type=checkbox]").val());
});
```